# GCM - Does the android phone needs to be connected on the internet to received this notification?

Tags: android

I'm just wondering how GCM works,

Does the android phone needs to be connected on the internet to received this notification?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. GCM clients receive notifications via a long-lived socket, maintained by the Google Services Framework, to the Internet.